# Calculate sum of differences between rows but only if the previous cell is bigger than the current one

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula

I started to get a headache around my problem that I cannot figure out for the love of me.
There are unknown amounts of column if that makes any difference, but basically each row needs to be compared to the previous one and ONLY when the previous value is greater, the difference between them gets added to the sum.

So for example I have this table

```
  |  A  |
--|-----|
1 | 100 |
2 |  90 |
3 |  80 |
4 | 100 |
5 |  70 |
6 |  20 |
7 | 100 |
...
```

Expected result: 100, derived from ((100-90) + (90-80) + (100-70) + (70-20))

I have spent a whole day browsing every single excel tutorial page and cannot find a single helpful answer. Please help :(

Comment: If you are able to create a helper column in B:B it is quite easy. Are you?

Comment: Preferably not, but in these moments of despair everything is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for Cell B2: (pull down through the rows).

```
=IF(A1>B1;A1-B1;0)+B1
```

Logic: If previous value is larger than current value, add the difference to the total.

Comment: Thank you for your immense help. I actually used a modified version of this, =IF(AND(A1>A2;A1-A2<>A1);A1-A2;"") which also fixes the last row not being taken since the next row is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one formula, a basic way would be two use two ranges offset by one cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6-A2:A7)*(A1:A6>A2:A7))
```

If you wanted to make a bit more dynamic (assuming there are no gaps in  the data) you could try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-1)-A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)))*(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-1)>A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A))))
```

[image]

If there are blanks between numbers, this won't work and you would probably need to go back to a simpler pull-down formula

Comment: Haven't actually tought of this way of solving it. But still it may contain empty values (maybe 1 in 10.000) so I can't use this but thank you for showing me a new way of thinking!

Comment: Ah, I suspected this might be the case but thanks for letting me know.